# Django REST API does not call delete method from API page

Tags: django-rest-framework

In my `api.py` I have delete function which in turn call model delete function.
However when I call 
`curl -X DELETE url` (this always call model function not api function)

`api.py`

```
@action(permission_classes=[IsAdminOrInNamespaceOrReadOnly])
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = self.get_object()
```

Comment: What's the HTTP status of the curl command ?

Comment: Please add the code for `delete()` method and the complete url you are trying on curl.

Comment: I need to override method destroy not delete:
@action(permission_classes=[IsAdminOrInNamespaceOrReadOnly])
def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = self.get_object()